# can I to remove Python2 from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, python

I'm using WSL2 Ubuntu 18.04 and I fell that python2 is always troubling me. Also, python2 support has officially come to an end this year. I want to remove python2 so I came across a post on this exchange which said you can check what depends on Python2 using this command

```
$ apt remove python --simulate
```

I've never used this command so I think I wanted to ask what is it trying to convey

```
> apt remove python --simulate                                                                        ~@DESKTOP-UU4FRL9
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython-stdlib python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
Remv python [2.7.15~rc1-1]
```

One thing I understood  is the following package will be removed `libpython-stdlib python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal`

but what I didn't understand **165 not upgraded**. Does this mean these 165 packages depend on python2? If yes what are these packages? How can I list them?

Comment: The "not upgraded" number is unrelated to removing Python2. Removing Py2 from 18.04 is unwise - doing so will break your 18.04.

Comment: I suspected that. So I think the only option is to upgrade to 20.04 LTS

Comment: I don't see upgrading to 20.04 as the only option; https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python shows it's maintained by Ubuntu Core Developers (even if no upstream), and is a package with 5 years of support (unlike for example if it was found in 'universe' etc). Qt4 is dead upstream, but apps for it still exist in both windows and Ubuntu worlds esp. in corporate environments... if you start doing it for every upstream lib/tool you'll need to constantly use new software... but it's your decision.